# ODI numeric and date format mask in datastores

Tags: types, number-formatting, sqldatatypes, oracle-data-integrator

In Oracle Data Integrator, I am creating a file datastore which has numbers in the following format:

```
1.234.567,89-
      222,44
         ,56-
```

In Oracle I can use the to_number function with a format mask of `'FM999G999G999D999MI'` to convert the value. However, on adding this mask to the format field of the datastore in ODI, I always get an error on running the mapping that `String x,yy- is not a valid representation for a Number`

Similarly, I had an issue parsing date field of the format `DD.MM.YY/HH24:MI:SS`.

I can, of course, keep the values as string and convert them while loading to the target table itself. But I was wondering if there was a simpler way of parsing the fields as numeric and date beforehand.

Comment: I've removed the Oracle tag as you have an Oracle solution to the problem and you are specifically looking for an Oracle Data Integrator solution. If you feel that it is appropriate to include the Oracle tag then [edit] your answer to re-include it and explain what you would be looking for in an Oracle solution that is not `TO_NUMBER(value, 'FM999G999G999D999MI')`.